# Some question about Lie algebra of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

I have some question about the answer of [Lie algebra of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65784/lie-algebra-of-gl-n-mathbbc). In the picture below:

First,the definition of left action. What is the mean of $xX(x^{-1}y)$, I understand $X(x^{-1}y)$ as the value of vector field $X$ at $x^{-1}y$. Then ,how $x$ act on  $X(x^{-1}y)$ ? Is it $x_*(X(x^{-1}y))$ (I use the denote in Riemannian geometry)?

Second, What is $\widetilde{[a,b]}$ ? I don't know the mean of ~ over $[a,b]$.

> [image]

Comment: The meaning of the tilde is explained in that text, in fact! If $a$ is a tangent vector at the identity, $\tilde a$ is the unique left invariant vector field which takes the value $a$ at the identity element.

Comment: The $x$ on the right of your first red rectangle is a typo, and the differential of the map given by multiplication by $x$ should be in its place, so indeed it should be $x_*(M(x^{-1}y))$.

Comment: If you had asked this clarifications as comments on the answer, it is very probably that the author of that answer would have answered there.

Comment: I wrote the meaning of the tilde in my first comment above.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez   It is really misunderstand. Because it is too small , I see $\tilde a$ as $-$ over $a $.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - Thanks for having pointed out the typo! I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\in G={\rm Gl}_n (\mathbb{C}),\ x\in M_n(
 \mathbb{C})$ Define a vector field $X(a):=a\cdot x\ \ast$ where multiplication is matrix
 multiplication So $$
 L_b\ X(a)=bax =X(ba) $$ Hence $X$ is a left invariant vector field

If $e^{tx}$ is an integral curve at $I$, then $ae^{tx}$ is integral
 curve at $a$ : $$ \frac{d}{dt} ae^{tx}= L_a X(t)=X(ae^{tx}) $$

Recall the definition of Lie bracket in Lie group :
 $$ Ad_a : T_IG\rightarrow T_IG,\ Ad_a (x)= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} ae^{tx}a^{-1} $$

$$ [y,x](e):=\frac{d}{dt} Ad_{e^{ty}} (x) $$

Note that $$[y,x](e)=yx-xy = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}
\frac{\partial }{\partial s}
 e^{ty}e^{sx}e^{-ty}$$

Here
 $$ df\ L_a\ [y,x](e):=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}
\frac{\partial }{\partial s}
 f(ae^{ty}e^{sx}e^{-ty} )$$

In further recall the definition of $[Y,X](a)$ in Riemannian
manifold : If $\phi$ is flow of $Y$
 \begin{align*}
  [Y,X](a)&= \frac{d}{dt} d\phi_{-t} X_{\phi_t(a)} \\&=
   \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}
  \phi_t(a)e^{sx} e^{-ty}  \\&=
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}
  ae^{ty} e^{sx} e^{-ty}  \end{align*}

So we complete the proof