# Why $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ action on its tangent vector field can be treated as matrix multiplication?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, group-actions

In question [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979588/some-question-about-lie-algebra-of-gl-n-mathbbc?noredirect=1#comment4063936_1979588),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65784/lie-algebra-of-gl-n-mathbbc), $G=GL_n(\mathbb C)$, let 
$$
X:G\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb C)
$$
is a tangent vector field, define the left action on tangent vector field as
$$
l(a)X(b)=a_*(X(a^{-1}b))  ~~~~\forall a,b\in G
$$
 $X$ is left invariant ,if
$$
l(a)X(b)=X(ab)   ~~~~\forall a,b\in G
$$
Assume $X$ is left invariant and $X(1)=x$, then why is
$$
X(a)=a\cdot x 
$$
the right is matrix multiplication  ?

PS: Maybe ,there are some errors in my question ,I just begin Lie algebra and am not familiar with it. And I use the language of Riemannian geometry, so I use its notations.